# Are Content Provider Column id's always unique no matter the case?

Tags: android-room, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

e.g

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID.
```

The reason why Im asking is because Im reading music data and writing them into Room database. I dont want there to be a situation where a song cant be added because it's using an ID stored in my Room database.

This is how I write the data to Room. I have to use this conflict strategy or else it keeps adding back deleted songs.

```
@Transaction
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun addSongs(song: SongTrack)
```

I have this query that removes everything from a `SongTrack` entity apart from the ID/ DbId(ID/ DbId is just to log deleted songs).

```
@Query("UPDATE songtrack SET albumUri = null, 
 songTitle = '', albumTitle= '' " + ", genre = '', image = '' WHERE id = 
:songId" )
fun removeBySongId(songId: Int)
```

Heres the entity:

```
@Entity
data class SongTrack(

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
var dbId: Int,
val id: Int,
val songTitle: String,
val artistName: String,
val albumUri: String?,
val image: String?,
val duration: Long,
val albumTitle: String,
val genre: String)
```

Hopefully this all makes sense. If Column Ids are forever unique even if someone has deleted that data on their phone my approach is safe.

Otherwise, how can I prevent room from adding back data I removed from Room database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just naming a column **id** does not make it a `UNIQUE` column. What makes a column `UNIQUE` is having a `UNIQUE` index on the column.

In your case the **dbId** column/field has an implicit `UNQIUE index` as it is defined as the `PrimaryKey`. So the **dbId** column MUST be a `UNIQUE value`.

- If an attempt is made to add a row where the value of the **dbId** already exists in another row then a `UNIQUE conflict` will occur and as you have found you can negate the failure by using `INSERT OR IGNORE` i.e. the `onConflictStrategy` of `IGNORE`.

As such your code will prevent another row being added if the **dbId** value already exists in the table.

The question says:-

> *I have this query that removes everything from a SongTrack entity apart from the ID/ DbId(ID/ **DbId is just to log deleted songs**).*

However, the **id** column/field does **not** have a `UNIQUE index` and thus any row can have any value in the **id** column/field; only if the **dbId** column/field is not a unique value would the row not be inserted due to the ignored unique conflict.

If you wanted the **id** column/field to also be unique then you cannot have multiple primary keys (although you can have a primary key (a composite primary key) that consists of multiple columns but then it is the combination of the columns that is UNIQUE not an individual column).

Room does not cater, via annotation of columns/fields, for a composite primary key nor for `UNIQUE` indexes. You have to use the `primaryKeys` and/or `indices` parameter of the `@Entity` annotation to define these indexes.

If you want the **id** column to also be UNIQUE (i.e. as well as the dbId column) then you would have to use the `indices` parameter e.g.

```
@Entity(indices = [Index("id", unique = true)])
```

With the above added then **dbId** would have to be `UNIQUE` and also **id** would have to be `UNIQUE` and a conflict of either or both would result in the insert being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I'll give this a go